# iPhone - Threading and Delegation

Tags: iphone, multithreading, delegation

I'm running some code in a background thread to get a text file from a service. That code fires a delegate at some point. It throws as SIGABRT error once the delegate is being called and well, my concept doesn't sound convincing to me either.

The code running at the background thread:

```
- (void)FetchStores
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

    // Fetch from service
    NSString *serviceURL = @"http://../index.html";
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:serviceURL];
    NSData *dataRep = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

    storesList = [[Stores alloc] init];
    storesList.storesDelegate = self;
    [storesList FetchWithNSData:dataRep];

    [pool release];
}
```

The `storesList` object will fire a delegate once all the stores have been extracted from the service. The delegate is getting caught by a function at the main thread.

Do you have any suggestions what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you,

f.

Comment: SIGABRT usually means an exception. What is the message in log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling the delegate, somewhere, you should make the switch to the main thread.
Especially if somewhere, you are updating the UI based on the data fetched.

You can use 
`- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait`
to make the switch.

Maybe like this:

```
storesList = [[Stores alloc] init];
storesList.storesDelegate = self;
[storesList performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(FetchWithNSData:) withObject:dataRep waitUntilDone:TRUE];
```

In your case, you should use `waitUntilDone:TRUE` so that the FetchWithNSData method gets a chance to retain the data.

Comment: Thank you for that. It solved the SIGABRT, but the app is misbehaving later on i.e. it's not working as it does when I'm not using a bg thread. Do you have any ideas? Should I try something else for threading? Thanks again! f.

Comment: What do you use for threading. You only showed use the code of the thread. Can you edit your post and copy-paste the part where you start your thread?

Comment: Personally I didn't manually use threads so far. There are already some classes from UIKit that work on a separate thread without you worrying about it. For example, I use NSURLConnection to download stuff on a different thread. It makes sure that it calls my delegate methods on the main thread so I can safely update UI or do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It seems quite likely that `FetchWithNSData:` does not retain the passed `dataRep` and the data gets deallocated on the next line where you drain the local autorelease pool?